# AngularJS ng-grid Export to Excel for selectedItems

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, export-to-excel, ng-grid

We have a ng-grid which displays data retrieved from a rest service. I want to export the rows selected by user(ng-grid selection check box enabled) to an excel and open that excel. The current behavior of app is Export to excel button calling a rest service with selected items from ng-grid and using POI to put the data into excel and returning the excel.

Is there a better way to do this? The data is already in browser, is there any angularjs, jQuery or javascript function to do this?

Comment: Maybe this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server) can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a plugin for csv export : https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/tree/master/plugins

It can be easily added by adding it to your gridoptions, while making sure to display the footer.

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: ...,
        plugins: [new ngGridCsvExportPlugin()],
        showFooter: true,
        ...
      };
```

It exports all your records from your specified grid.data.

[Although you can pass in an options object for specifying columns etc. there isn't an option currently to limit to selectedItems.]

It looks easy though to adjust the ng-grid-csv-export.js source to loop over grid.mySelections instead over grid.data. (not tested by me yet)

Comment: Looks easy to change the data to grid.mySelections, will try it. but How should I move that csv data to excel now in javaScript.

Comment: You can copy text to the user's clipboard and ask user to paste it in Excel. The values should be tab delimited.

Comment: The link is not available now. can you provide needed help?

Comment: @sms the plugin is still available on some of forked repos. Such as this one : https://github.com/choroshin/ng-grid/tree/master/plugins